# Phonegap on iOS9 localhost http(s)?

Tags: ios, cordova, ssl, https, phonegap-build

I'm testing how the app I'm building would work in iOS9 in the beta release of Xcode 7.

This lead me to wonder how everything will be served to the app, as it runs on a localhost connection over HTTP, and it seems that won't be possible in iOS9 without [bypassing ATS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30751053/ios9-ats-what-about-html5-based-apps).

Can/Should Cordova based apps be configured to run the localhost over https?

Comment: cordova apps aren't serverd from http, they are serverd using file protocol, so it shouldn't affect. It might affect if the app is using the WKWebview that uses a local web server, but I haven't tryied

Comment: It actually is using WKWebview, and from reading this: https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/WKWebView/issues/127 it seems this might not be an issue in ios9