# Objective-C UIWebView not loading website

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am trying to get a UIWebView to display google.com for now, but its not loading:

I just get a blank screen

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
    [_webView loadRequest:request];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

What I did is the following to create a web view:

- Created a new UIViewController scene
- Added a UIWebView to it
- connected the webview to .h controller
- Made my scene the inital scene
- Ran the app, nothing was loaded, no errors, just go straight to UIViewController with nothing in it, please help.

I tried adding the following:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.webView];
```

That did nothing

Comment: did you try [webView loadRequest:request]; , Also you have to consume webview property in your implementation.

Comment: it doesnt make sense when  tried adding it as subview ,when outlet is already there

Answer (score 6):

If You're running Web View on iOS > 9.0, probably You haven't added NSAppTransportSecurity key to project *.plist file, so the app can't request any URL.

If You want to allow all of URL request, then following code should be added to project plist file:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

else if You want to allow only specific URL request:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>allowed.domain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 2):

add Break point , check if `NSURLRequest *request` is nil ,
if nil, then do

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://www.yourWebAddress.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

try to encode the url...hope it will works

Answer (score 1):

Try adding :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Check if the web view is linked correctly from the XIB
    NSLog(@"WebView : %@",_webView);
    _webView.delegate = self;


    NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
    [_webView loadRequest:request];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

and add this new method in your class (also implement UIWebViewDelegate in te .h)

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
   //Check if the web view loadRequest is sending an error message
   NSLog(@"Error : %@",error);
}
```

Comment: This is what was in my console: `WebView : <UIWebView: 0x17e8e5c0; frame = (0 0; 240 128); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x17e8e7c0>>`

Comment: And never print the didFailLoadWithError Log??

Comment: Thank you!! `didFailLoadWithError` helped me finding my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really using an outlet for webview, then this should work no matter what.

```
   [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]];
```

Comment: make sure the outlet is connected in storyboard

Answer (score 1):

Allow AppTransport permission to yes in Info.plist

Answer (score 0):

Would you happen to be building in Xcode 7 and targeting iOS 9?

If so, you're likely running into the new default security requirement for accessing sites via https, as detailed here:

[Disabling ATS for an in-app browser in iOS 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32106994/disabling-ats-for-an-in-app-browser-in-ios-9)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is that you call seter (_webView). Try through:

```
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```