# how to update Info.plist in cordova app

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-ios

I have the problem described here in a cordova app:
[iOS9 ATS: what about HTML5 based apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30751053/ios9-ats-what-about-html5-based-apps)

... I don't see an Info.plist outside of the platforms/ios directory that I can add that config to.  Everything inside platforms/ios gets clobbered/replaced when I build the app.

So, is there a way to update the Info.plist with that new config that is permanent?

Thanks!

Comment: you can create a plugin without native code and make the plugin.xml write values on the .plist

Comment: If you want to automate a build, you could parse that file with some XML parser (or just using regular expressions), inject the option and write file back.

Answer (score 0):

In my projects I'm using my own cordova-ios fork which has a mentioned by you change in the template project's Info.plist file (it requires `cordova platform add url_to_your_fork`), although you can invoke in your `<PROJECT_NAME>/platforms/ios/<PROJECT_NAME>`:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy <PROJECT_NAME>-Info.plist -c "Add :NSAppTransportSecurity:NSAllowsArbitraryLoads bool true"
```

Straight after `cordova platform add ios`, or add it as a Cordova `after_platform_add` hook