# Will Apple reject my app if I bypass the ATS (App Transport Security) for my PhoneGap app?

Tags: ios, cordova

Will Apple reject my app if I bypass the ATS (App Transport Security) for my PhoneGap app as mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30751053/ios9-ats-what-about-html5-based-apps)?  I cannot change my server configuration as it's build on top of cloud backend that doesn't support HTTPS. Does it mean I will have to throw my app for iOS 9 or change complete backend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. For now you can freely configure your plist to set NSAllowsArbitraryLoads or NSExceptionDomains. Apple will not reject your app for this.

[edit]

However, there is a plan for Apple to restrict it someday. See https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12212016b

Comment: @nickalchemist Yes it will.

Comment: Will accept it if I don't get any mail from Apple for this. :) Thanks!