# Websocket connection not happening in iOS9

Tags: ios, cordova, websocket, ios9.3

I've a `cordova` release. But now if I build and check Xcode7.3 `webSocket` connection is opening and then directly going to `onclose()`.

Comment: Any error messages? Crash logs? MCVE code snippet? There's no information in this question to enable anyone to assist you.

Comment: I think this is the problem I am facing
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30751053/ios9-ats-what-about-html5-based-apps