# Visual Studio Cordova Missing Info.plist key

Tags: ios, xcode, visual-studio, cordova, info.plist

I´m using visual studio for developing cordova applications.

If I upload my App to the Store with Xcode8, I get the following error mail.

`Missing Info.plist key - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.`

Based on an other stackoverflow-question I´ve added the plugin `https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-transport-security` and modified the plugin.xml:

`<platform name="ios">
    <config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSAppTransportSecurity">
      <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
        <string>This app requires access to the photo library.</string>
        <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
        <string>This app does not require access to the microphone.</string>
        <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
        <string>This app requires access to the camera.</string>
      </dict>
    </config-file>
  </platform>`

In my config.xml:

`<plugin name="cordova-plugin-transport-security" version="0.1.2" src="C:\Users\xxx\cordova-plugin-transport-security-master\cordova-plugin-transport-security-master" />`

After that i build the app for iOS and uploaded it via xcode.

But the error is still there.

Comment: check out the answer i have posted in the link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41525725/phonegap-missing-plist-key Looks like a similar issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With that change you are writing the `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` and the other UsageDescriptions inside `NSAppTransportSecurity`, it should be on the root.

If you use latest version of cordova-plugin-media-capture, it already have the [needed values](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture/blob/master/plugin.xml#L149-L162)

```
        <preference name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" default=" " />
        <config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSCameraUsageDescription">
            <string>$CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION</string>
        </config-file>

        <preference name="MICROPHONE_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" default=" " />
        <config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSMicrophoneUsageDescription">
            <string>$MICROPHONE_USAGE_DESCRIPTION</string>
        </config-file>

        <preference name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" default=" " />
        <config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription">
            <string>$PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION</string>
        </config-file>
```

The value is `$CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION` because it's picked from a variable whey you install the plugin from the CLI. As you use Visual Studio, I think you can set the value using a variable tag in the config.xml.
The variable tags should be inside the plugin that will use them:

```
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" spec="~1.4.1">
        <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="your camera usage message" />
        <variable name="MICROPHONE_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="your microphone usage message" />
        <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="your photolibrary usage message" />
    </plugin>
```

If that doesn't work, you can continue using your modified plugin, but add each UsageDescription as a separate `config-file` tag as in the previous code.

Comment: Thank you. At first, I tried it with adding the variable tag to the config.xml directly inside the `<widget>` tag. That doesn´t work. Should i place the variable tag in another hierarchy? After that, I replaced the variable in `plugin.xml` with a string. Now it works. :)

Comment: @alexander-fire I edited the answer, the variable tag goes inside the plugin that uses it. If my answer helped you, you can accept the answer