# Ionic 5 Image Picker crashes in iOS Simulator

Tags: ionic-framework, ios-simulator, ionic-native, imagepicker

I try to simply integrate the image picker in my Tab Page. I have a ion-button which calls the Method chooseImage() on a click.

The Problem ist, that when I start the app in the iOS Simulator, it starts normal, but when I click on the chooseImage Button it crashes in that moment. The Image Picker does not open, it crashes before, directly at the click on the button....  I don't know why. Maybe someone could help me please!

This is the Method:

```
chooseImage() {
  this.options = {
    width: 220,
    quality: 32,
    outputType: 1,
    maximumImagesCount: 5
  };

  this.imageObj = [];
  this.imagePicker.getPictures(this.options).then((res) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
      this.imageObj.push('data:image/jpeg;base64,' + res[i]);
    }
  }, (error) => {
    alert(error);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you miss `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` in your `Info.plist`. You should add this:

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Some description</string>
```

Where and how add these lines?

This will be helpful if you use `cordova`: [Add entry to iOS .plist file via Cordova config.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22769111/add-entry-to-ios-plist-file-via-cordova-config-xml)

If you use `capacitor` check [documentation](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/ios/configuration#configuring-infoplist).